# MySQL Select Product-SimilarProduct

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have two tables products and similar_products. Products tables holds data related to available products however this tables has loads of products that are same but with different product id. Which is why I have another table that hold the data for all the similar products. I need to run a query that selects products from products table but at the same also check in similar_products tables to not select any duplicate products.

So for example:

Products Table:

```
ProductID | Manufacturer  | Part No     | Name
-----------------------------------------------------------------
8202      | Hp            | 402146-B21  | HP Auto Synch Cable
8210      | Hp            | 113894-B21  | HP Stylus 3 Pack
8211      | Hp            | 113894-B21  | HP Stylus 3 Pack
8212      | Hp            | 113894-B21  | HP Stylus 3 Pack
```

Similar_products Table

```
ProductID | Similar_ProductID
----------|-------------------
8210      | 8211
8210      | 8212
8211      | 8210
8211      | 8212
8212      | 8210
8212      | 8211
```

How can I run a query that will only select ProductID 8202 and 8210 and not select duplicates products.

Comment: If product x is similar to product y, does it follow (as it seems it should) that product y is similar to product x? In other words, will there always be a duplicate?

Comment: If product x is similar to product y, and product y is similar to product z, does it imply that product x is also similar to product z, by transitivity? Also,  in your example, How come 8202 is selected when it is not similar in any way to 8210?

Comment: @Strawberry No not all products will have duplicate but some product are similar but has different productid but when creating export for magento store I can't export duplicate products which why I need to select just one product from all the duplicates for given product.

Comment: @KyleDomingo yes it does and I also have the data ready for similar_products table I am just not sure how to write a query that does what I need

Comment: @MaggsWeb because sometimes we have same products from different suppliers that uses different part_no

Comment: You have both records [8210, 8211] and [8211, 8210] in Similar_products, describing the relationship "from both perspectives". a) is that always/reliably the case? b) would it be ok to always select the lowest ProductId of a group of similar products?

Comment: Your association table is not helping you at all.

Comment: @MaggsWeb DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: side note: Your text tables are pretty, but providing sample data as valid `INSERT INTO ...` statements makes it much easier to fiddle with the problem ...

Comment: @VolkerK: copy and paste the pretty text tables into SQLFiddle's 'Text to DDL' option. It creates the schema automatically for you.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51371

Comment: I think something like this would be better representative of the problem... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53c2cf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you always have the relationship x~y as the two records [x,y] and [y,x] in Similar_products your problem is a variation of [The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

```
SELECT
    p.ProductID, p.Name
FROM
    Products as p
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            Similar_products s
        WHERE
            p.ProductID=s.ProductID
            AND p.ProductID>s.Similar_ProductID
    )
```